# How to create a Java file dynamically into certain package using Ant concat task?

Tags: ant, parameters, concatenation

I have an `Ant` script file in which I use `concat` task to create a Java cource file in the specified package which is defined in a properties file.

For example, I define the package name:

```
ma.package=com.my.package
```

In `Ant` script, I call:

```
<concat destfile="./${prject.root}/${ma.package}/MyClass.java">
```

However, `MyClass.java` was created in a subfolder `com.my.package`, instead of folder structure `com\my\package`. How to fix it?

I use Eclipse Helios under Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [PathConvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) with a nested [UnpackageMapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) to convert the package name to a path. For example:

```
<project default="test">

  <property name="ma.package" value="com.my.package"/>

  <target name="test">
    <pathconvert property="ma.package.dir">
      <path path="${ma.package}"/>
      <unpackagemapper from="*" to="*"/>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo message="ma.package : ${ma.package}"/>
    <echo message="ma.package.dir : ${ma.package.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

The output is:

```
Buildfile: C:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
 [echo] ma.package : com.my.package
 [echo] ma.package.dir : C:\tmp\ant\com\my\package
```

So you could use the converted property value in your concat:

```
<concat destfile="${ma.package.dir}/MyClass.java">
```